# Is it possible to add some custom data to the event payload body or headers sent to a Bitbucket webhook?

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I want to add a few strings to the existing event payload that is delivered to a webhook. It doesn't matter if i can send them in the payload body or as Custom HTTP Headers.

I've checked the documentation of the event payload and I've checked my webhook settings but i'm not able to find any clues which would allow me do such a thing so I'm wondering if it is even possible.

I'm using Bitbucket cloud.

Comment: I also want to know the same thing

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to implement this in time. If I had the time, I'd have looked into the Bitbucket cloud rest API to implement this.